# Getting Error while installing SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I don't know why I am getting this error on my machine while installing SQL Server. I have tried installing 2008, 2012, 2014 versions but getting same error again and again. I have checked control panel to find any files of previous SQL server but nothing is there. Can any one guide me about this error. I have already wasted lot of time to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already checked [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f37e18eb-f1ab-4106-83f6-8bbf04d6a41a/setup-failed-0x84b10001-sql-2012-hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position)?

Comment: @MatSnow yes I have tried this. Still unsolved. Don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

here below link explain error details

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4276/sql-server-setup-error--there-was-an-error-generating-the-xml-document-error-code-0x84b10001/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2379466/fix-0x84b10001-error-code-sql-server-2008-or-sql-server-2008-r2-setupm

Comment: does not those link helpful？

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the installation path is too long or has many spaces.

Comment: I am getting this error right after clicking on SQL Server Standalone installation option.